# FindViewById is undefined?

Tags: android, class, extend, countdowntimer

Hi I am having trouble defining findViewById in my function. Below is my function:

```
if(test.mStartedWalking == false){
        TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.myText); 
        myText.append (lsNow + '\n');
        test.mStartedWalking = true;
}
```

I get an error that says: The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type StepDisplayer and I am pretty sure it is because my class does not extend a type Activity. However, how would I correct this? The class implements this instead:

```
public class StepDisplayer implements StepListener, SpeakingTimer.Listener
```

I am unable to extend an activity as I know Java only extends one class or can implement more than one interface. Might anyone know how to fix this? If so that would be great! Thanks!

Comment: when you create the instance of the `StepDisplayer` you can pass the reference to the `CurrentActivity` to this class... Assuming that you are creating the instance from an `Activity` class..

Comment: pass the context to StepDisplayer from your activity class and use that in StepDisplayer.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, your class can extend a single class and implement multiple interfaces. Since your class `StepDisplayer` only implements `StepListener` and `SpeakingTimer.Listener` interfaces, you can make it extend the `Activity` class.

**E.g:**

```
public class StepDisplayer extends Activity implements StepListener, SpeakingTimer.Listener
```

---

In case you cannot do that for whatsoever reasons, you can pass the `Context` from the Activity class which is calling the said method in StepDisplayer and use that to call the `findViewById` method.

```
yourMethodInStepDisplayerClass(IAmCallingStepDisplayerActivity.this);
```

Comment: So you can implement AND extend a class? Do u mind giving an example of this?

Answer (score 1):

`findViewById()` method is available in `Activity` class. So if your class in not extending Activity, you should pass activity context to the class where you want to call `findViewById()`. And then simply call

```
context.findViewById(int id) ;
```

:-)

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
public class StepDisplayer extends Activity implements StepListener, SpeakingTimer.Listener
```